# PHP array_map looping to itself

Tags: php, rest

I´m creating an rest server using some examples in internet. The source is: 
https://github.com/danucu/GUS/blob/master/restfulengine/restfulobj.php

The problem is when I´m making a call to the object, it calls itself again in the method getMyVars:

```
protected function getMyVars($myVars = null) {
    if (empty($myVars)) {
        $myVars = $this->showMyPublicsOnly();
    }
    if (is_array($myVars)) {
        /*
         * Intorc array convertit la obiect
         * utilizand __METHOD__ (constanta ;) )
         * pentru apelurile recursive
         */
        return array_map(__METHOD__, $myVars);
    } else {
        // intorc array
        return $myVars;
    }
}
```

The full rest object is here:

https://github.com/danucu/GUS/blob/master/restfulengine/usertest.php

When Whe I run localhost/rest/UserREST/example it runs in a infinite loop.

I have changed the method getMyWars to:

```
     echo $this->method."\n\n";
     echo __METHOD__."\n\n";

     $arReturn = array_map(__METHOD__, $myVars);

     print_r($arReturn);
```

And I got:

```
  GET

 restObject::getMyVars
```

...infinitely and it never reaches: print_r($arReturn);

Maybe I´m doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that code looks really strange, it will always call itself to the end of the times (or at least until the call stack overflows). Let me explain:

```
if (is_array($myVars)) { //is_array === true
    return array_map(__METHOD__, $myVars); // This will call __METHOD__ (getMyVars); and pass $myVars to it (which is an array).
} else { //This will never be reached.
    return $myVars;
}
```

Comment: `__METHOD__` will be passed all values in `$myVars` one by one, won't it? *Not* the original array.

Answer (score 0):

Your code *apparently* works. What I think is happening is this:

- first call: getMyVars() get passed, say, null.
- this is empty, so it gets `$this->showMyPublicsOnly()`
- this is an array, so every member of that array gets applied getMyVars()...
- **...but one of those values is equivalent to empty**.

So if you have, say,

```
[ 'varOne' => 'Hello', 'varTwo' => 'World', 'varThree' => 42 ];
```

it will work, but

```
[ 'varOne' => '', ]
```

will loop.

You can try this:

```
// Only iterate on non-empty values
$myVars = array_filter($myVars);
// If there are no non-empty values...
if (empty($myVars)) {
    /* ...this would loop, so we return an empty array */
    return [ ];
}
return array_map(__METHOD__, $myVars);
```